# Gmail api to use custom domain

Tags: gmail-api, google-schemas

I want to use gmail with custom domain for my customers. Can I setup a gmail account with custom domain using api? Is there any docs? Any experience?

Thanks a lot.

Eric

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Apps For Business system http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/ is the official way to do what you want. For more than a very few users, it costs money, however.

I use it on my personal domain (it was easy to set up alongside GAE for some personal projects) and it works just like Gmail.

Comment: Ah well, at least it's still free for me. I get the impression Eric wants more than four users anyway.

Comment: Yes. Paid is not a problem. This is what I want to accomplish. I have a website where user can buy domain name through my website. I also need a service so user can have their email with their custom domain name. I need to setup a gmail account programatically from my website to use the custom domain.